# Parse string for doubles

Tags: c#, string, parsing, double

I need to parse the string for the doubles it contains and store it in a list of doubles so later I can take the values and store them in a variable.

[image]

You can see on the picture in the richtextbox I have the string content now I tried to parse it like this

```
public void GetAll()
{       
   List<double> doubles = new List<double>();
   MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(buff, @"(([-]|[+])?\d+[.]\d+)");         
   foreach (Match match in matches)
   {
       string val = match.Groups[1].Value;
       doubles.Add(double.Parse(val));        
   }
}
```

and it doesnt store the doubles in the list.
I need them stored in order they show up `doubles[0]` = value of vv_in, `doubles[1]` = values of vv_out and so on.

Comment: Why not use `double.TryParse` instead of regex. If it returns true, you have a valid double in its out-parameter.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It looks like the OP needs to first parse the numeric part out of the string.

Comment: what is the content of `buff` ? is it a string containing the entire text from the textbox?

Comment: If it doesn't find the doubles, what *does* it do?  Are there any matches for that regex on that string?  What are they?  What exactly is the string and can you parse it another way?  Perhaps split by carriage returns, further split by whitespace, etc.?

Comment: Use a Dictionary<string, double> behind the scenes that stores all the values of the text boxes, then when writing to your RichTextBox iterate and concatenate the keys with the values.

Comment: I have tried your code and I am unable to reproduce the problem. The numbers appears in the order in which they are listed in those rows. However your code doesn't explain what is the content of _buff_ Perhaps they are already messed up there.

Comment: @MongZhu  the content of buff is the entire textbox yes

Comment: @Steve i send commands troght serial port and i receive the content of the textbox back when i read from it. now i need to parse the string for doubles and store them in a list of doubles in the order they show up in the textbox

Comment: OK, but you use a variable _buff_ that we don't know how do you intialize it. If I prepare a string variable with a sample taken from your image I can parse it with your code correctly and the numbers appear in the list exactly in the order in which they are written on the test variable. What is the content of the _buff_ variable when you call this method? (And why don't you pass it as parameter instead of using a global variable. I digress.)

Comment: what is your culture? do you get an output like `1183, 1178, ...` ?

Comment: After the last edit I think you should really clarify what is your problem. Do you have the numbers stored in the list or not? If they are stored in the list are them in the order you want? Or do you have something that is not your original number but an integer with the decimal point removed? Despite you providing the code your problem is unclear.

Comment: To continue on Steves comment, please add what is the content of `val` when you debug the code and the value of the expression `double.Parse` (e.g. by examining a watch). In particular that clearifies what you exactly mean by "doesn´t store the values".

Answer (score 4):

You want to store the double that might be at the end of the strings? I'd use this approach:

```
List<double> doubles = new List<double>();
string[] lines = yourTextBox.Lines;
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    int lastSpaceIndex = line.LastIndexOf(' ');
    string doubleToken = line.Substring(++lastSpaceIndex);
    double d;
    if(double.TryParse(doubleToken, out d))
        doubles.Add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't really test it without your data, but this is worth a try:

```
var doubles = from line in buff.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              from item in line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              where double.TryParse(item, out var _)
              select double.Parse(item);
```

As mentioned in the comments, this uses discards, which are a C# 7 feature.

Comment: `string.Split` splits at spaces by default, no need to provide `' '`  to it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works almost fine. The only thing you have to tune, it that `Parse` needs to take the culture into account. And I changed your regex so it can cope with optional decimal digits:

```
List<double> doubles = new List<double>();

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(buff, @"(([-]|[+])?\d+(.\d+)?)");  
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string val = match.Groups[1].Value;
    doubles.Add(double.Parse(val, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should first split your values into single lines and then every line at the whitespaces. At last try to parse the second part of the obtained array into a double:

```
public void GetAll()
{

   List<double> doubles = new List<double>();
   foreach(var line in buff.Split('\n')
   {
       var parts = line.Split();
       if(parts.Length == 3)
       {
           double d;
           if(double.TryParse(parts[2], out d)
               doubles.Add(d);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this wouldn't work given the input in the question, and thats assuming `buff` is even the textarea contents.  I was not the downvoter however

Comment: @maccettura Indeed I missed a space. Apart from this: what else should `buff` be, as it obviously must contain a number

Comment: @HimBromBeere This still wouldn't work, at all. The OP's code assumes `buff` is the *complete* input from the text box. You're assuming a single number needs to be extracted from that. The OP attempts to extract all numbers from it.

Comment: @hvd I don´t see your point, where are more than one number in `"VA W_IN 11.83"`? Or you ment *all lines*?

Comment: @HimBromBeere hvd's point is that you are missing a loop to get *every* number

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, all lines. Based on the question, `buff` looks like it's supposed to be `"VA W_IN 11.83\nVA W_OUT 11.78\n..."` (or possibly with `\r\n`)

Comment: @HimBromBeere i mean all the content in the textbox to be parsed for the doubles it contains and they be stored in a list of doubles the content in textbox is stored in string "buff"

Comment: @xBehemoth Then `buff.Split('\n')` will simply split your textbox-content into an array containing *all* the lines. Then for each line you may proceed as I´ve told above. I can´t see your problem still.